# What are the subject and predicate in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

What are the subject and predicate in the following sentence?

*What a crazy Email Chain.*

Answer (score 2):

**What a crazy email chain!**

This is an exclamatory sentence and would normally end in an exclamation mark to convey an emotion.

Note that it does not contain a subject or verb. However, we can rewrite it to add in its *implied* subject and verb: ‘What a crazy email chain [this is].’

[This] is the (implied) subject.

‘[is] a crazy email chain’ is the predicate.

And ‘What’ is the object complement: it modifies 'a crazy email chain'.